# Is it good practice to have individual database for testing an application for each developer

Tags: sql, asp.net, web

My company has decided that each developer should have its own database locally for testing the Asp.net web application. I am against the decision as I think there should be a centralised test database for testing. But the developers put an argument that if they test the same table and other developers delete the records while I add the records at the same time it will create incorrect result. So what you guys think.

Comment: I think you are right .. a centralized db for testing application is better and the test must be consistent .. for sigle developer is useful a personal  .. test and trail workplace .. but not for application test

Comment: Why not both?  Centralized database instances for deployed application instances (dev, QA, etc.) and workstation database instances maintained by each developer.  Connect to the appropriate database as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Each developer should have their own database if they are going to be making any changes to the data structure or values. If one of the devs adds/removes something that prevents a portion of code from working it will only affect that dev instead of all the devs. This also allows devs to get more comfortable with the data structure and making changes to it since they can break/fix their own environment as much as they want.

There should be a testing environment that has its own database where the current revision of the project can run for tests.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a good practice (for integration tests for example), but it's acceptable for functional tests (or smoke tests) on development environment. The thing is that, it's better to integrate database and application from the very initial steps, thus you will avoid issues, bugs, waste of time. Also, make sure the developers don't make changes on schema, you should have a unique and well identified database version.

Answer (score 0):

> But the developers put an argument that if they test the same table and other developers delete the records while I add the records at the same time it will create incorrect result.

Sounds like a really bad web application.  A good web application should be able to support more than one simultaneous user!

For that reason alone, perhaps your team should at least have a phase where people are sharing a common database.